# Saving programmatically an ImageField duplicates the image file

Tags: django, imagefield

I'm creating some instances of the `Item` model shown below from a csv file. In the csv file only the `name` and the `filename` of the Item is specified. The `image` field is set by looking if the image exists, and if it does, set the image file to `image`:

I do:

```
item = Item()
item.name = csv_fields[0]
item.filename = csv_fields[1]
item.save()

...

f = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"images/"+item.filename, 'r')
item.image = File(f)
item.save()
```

Doing so, the image is duplicated in `settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"images/"` as `<original filename>_1`. How can avoid that? i.e. how can I just set an existing file to an imagefield,  without copying it?

```
class Item(models.Model):   

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need

```
item = Item()
item.name = csv_fields[0]
item.filename = csv_fields[1]
item.image = csv_fields[1]
item.save()
```

the image field takes a filename and the field definition's upload_to, and converts that to an image resource. if you pass in an image resource, it thinks its making a new one.

SO this:

```
f = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"images/"+item.filename, 'r')
item.image = File(f)
```

isn't necessary at all

the only diff between a charfield and a image field is that a imagefield takes the filename and casts it to a PIL Image resource for further manipulation. its just a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Francis Yaconiello answer is correct, but I have one clarifying detail.

```
item.image = csv_fields[1]
```

Note that this should be a path relative to the media root or other storage root.

For example, say `settings.MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/myuser/media'` and the `ImageField(upload_to='images')`.

So if you manually save an image at `/home/myuser/media/images/purty.jpg', then csv_fields[1] should be:

```
item.image = '/images/purty.jpg'
```

Other wise, item.image.name, item.image.path, and item.image.url will be messed up.